# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x}$ without using L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, calculator

Help me calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x}$$

Comment: A similar question: [Find $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\cos(2t)-1}{\cos(t)-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525373)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{2\sin^2 x}{2\sin^2\frac{x}2}.$$

Comment: Very nice hint. +1

Comment: Nice hint, but what's next +1

Comment: Now use $\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 1$, $t \to 0$.

Comment: It would also be good to remember that $$\sin x=2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2\;$$ and get a great cancellation (and then an almost trivial limit)

Answer (score 5):

1. Use L'Hospital twice
   $$
   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-\cos 2x}{1 - \cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\left ( 1-\cos 2x \right )'}{\left( 1 - \cos x \right )'} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2\sin 2x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\left ( 2\sin 2x \right )'}{\left ( \sin x \right )'} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {4\cos 2x}{\cos x} = 4
   $$
2. Use Taylor series expansion of $\cos x$ around $0$
   $$
   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-1+\frac {4x^2}2 + O((2x)^4)}{1-1+\frac {x^2}2 + O(x^4)} = 4
   $$
3. Use double angle formula
   $$
   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2 - 2 \cos^2x}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2(1+\cos x) = 4
   $$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $1-(Taylor Series)$ in the numerator and denominator of Method 2?

Comment: @User58220 you're right. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cos 2x= \cos^2 x-\sin^2x$, which gives $1-\cos 2x=2\sin^2 x = 2(1-\cos^2x)$ and you can cancel the denominator.